# How to save a List of objects into mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

**Repo**

```
public interface AppPortRepository {

AppPortModel save(AppPortModel appPortModel);
void remove (AppPortModel appPortModel);
List<AppPortModel> findAll();
}
```

**Repo Impl**

```
@Repository
public class AppPortRepositoryImpl implements AppPortRepository {

    ApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("SpringConfig.xml");

    MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");

    @Override
    public AppPortModel save(AppPortModel appPortModel) {
        mongoOperation.save(appPortModel);
        return appPortModel;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(AppPortModel appPortModel) {
        mongoOperation.remove(appPortModel);

    }
    @Override
    public List<AppPortModel> findAll() {
        return mongoOperation.findAll(AppPortModel.class);
    }

}
```

**Pojo**

```
@Document(collection = "apData")
public class AppPortModel implements Comparable {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String status;
    private String host;
    private String portName;
    private String plCount;

    public AppPortModel () {}

    public AppPortModel (String status, String host, String portName, String plCount) {
        this.status = status;
        this.host = host;
        this.portName = portName;
        this.plCount = plCount;
    }

    //getters and setters

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.getHost().compareTo(((AppPortModel) o).getHost());
        //return (int) (this.getMemoryUtilization()-(((AppServerCpuDisk)o).getMemoryUtilization()));
    }

     @Override
     public String toString() {
      return "Employee [Status=" + status + ", Host=" + host + ", Port Name="
        + portName + ", Port Listening Count=" + plCount + "]";



     }
}
```

**class SNippet**

```
 public class ApplicationPort implements Runnable {
    @Autowired
    private AppPortRepositoryImpl appPortRepositoryImpl;

 /*code that gives me values of Status, apServer, n, and line
 ***********************************************
  removed code here to minimize clutter/code overwhelm.
 ***********************************************
   n means port Name, line means Count.  */  

    apData.add(new AppPortModel(Status,apServer,n,line));
    //apData stores all the data into a list

    //I tried to mock the method above to insert these values into MongoDB.
    AppPortModel appPortModel = new AppPortModel(Status,apServer,n,line);
                    appPortRepositoryImpl.save(appPortModel);
```

**Class to run thread**

```
 @Component
    public class AppPortList {      

    @Value("#{'${APP_SERVERS_PORT_MONITORING}'.split('@!')}")
    private String[] apServerArray;
    @Value("#{'${APP_SERVER_PORT_MONITORING_PORTS}'.split('@!')}")
    private String[] appServerPortsList;    

    @PostConstruct
    public List<AppPortModel> getAppPortList() {

    final int MYTHREADS = 80;
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MYTHREADS);

    //for loop
    //catch  and shut down executor
    return ApplicationPort.getData();
```

I am trying to store those varibles(PoJO) into MONGODB. Currently these values are being stored in a List. "List < AppPortModel>". I removed all the code in between because it was just methods on how I am getting my values. I followed few tutorials and this is how they saved their data into MONGO DB. I can save all my data into a List but I can save the data into Mongo Db

**Error Message**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.spring.web.server.ApplicationPort.run(ApplicationPort.java:134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This error points to "appPortRepositoryImpl.save(appPortModel);"

**SpringConfig.xml sample**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
          xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
          xsi:schemaLocation=
          "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Default bean name is 'mongo' -->
    <mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017"/>
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="allData" />

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Looks like your autowired repository is null. You probably need to enable component scanning somehow, or ensure your component scanning is searching the package where your repository implementation lives.

Comment: where is your spring boot class ? Can you please add that to post ? You need to set up configuration to scan classes there and then autowire them into your classes

Comment: @SagarReddy It would be class code snippet

Comment: I don't think you are using spring boot. is it a correct assumption ? you are trying to load the class through a thread right ?. Is there a main class for your application which launches this thread ?

Comment: @SagarReddy I've added the class that runs the thread

Comment: do you mind adding SpringConfig.xml ?

Comment: @SagarReddy I don't really have a SpringConfig.xml. I followed a tutorial and their springConfig basically connects to mongodb which I already have in my properties.file. I will add the SpringConfig that the tutorial used.

Comment: you need the config to register your beans and more. please follow the tutorials carefully as you are missing quite a few things

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130528/discussion-between-jackie-and-sagar-reddy).